# Passing jenkins variables to Job dsl script in a Pipeline file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

**Question**
How can I pass variables to a job dsl script embedded in a pipeline file. I have a Jenkins pipeline which sets some variables and I want to use these variables in the pipelineJob template in the pipeline. Tried different combinations but cant seem to get it right. For example, following is my pipeline which gets an input from the user i.e the git repo url.

```
    pipeline {
   agent any

           parameters {
            string(name: 'repo_url', defaultValue: '')
        }

   stages {
      stage('Input gathering') {
         steps {
             script {
                            env.repo_url = input message: 'Enter github url', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'repo_url', trim: false)]

             }
             echo "====${env.repo_url}======"
         }
      }
              stage('stage'){
            steps {
                // some other steps
                echo "====${env.repo_url}======"

                jobDsl scriptText: '''pipelineJob(\'new-job\') {


                    triggers {
                        scm(\'H/5 * * * *\')
                    }

                    definition {
                        cpsScm {
                            scm {
                                git {
                                    remote { 
                                        url(repo_url) 
                                        credentials('bitbucket-jenkins-access')
                                    }
                                    branches(\'master\')
                                    scriptPath(\'Jenkinsfile\')
                                    extensions { } 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }'''                    
            }           
        }
    }
   }
```